# How to combine multiple nested arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 sets of nested arrays:

```
var values = [[100, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 100, 100],
[87.5, 100, 100, 100, 87.5, 87.5],
[75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75],
[50, 50, 50, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5],
[62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 50, 37.5, 50],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

var date = [["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"]];
```

What I'm trying to do is combine each array in Values and Date:

```
Get this :[100, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 100, 100]
Get this :["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"]
```

Then combine like this:

```
[{y: 100, d:2015},{y:87.5, d: 2004},{y:87.5, d:2015}},{y:87.5, d:2015}},{y:100, d:2015}},{y:100, d:2015}]
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/zidski/5808pgs4/3/

```
 var result = values.map(function (n, i) {
            return ({ y: n, d: values[i] });
        });
```

But the whole array gets added.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz - "Then combine like this" - I think the OP did.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use a `flatMap` style function, and maybe a `reduce`. http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

Comment: The "then combine like this" isn't clear, it doesn't match up with the data in the arrays of arrays, and it's not clear how that mapping is supposed to get flattened.

Comment: you need two nested `Array#map` calls. Like `grid.map((row, y) => row.map((item, x) => ... ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the inner array as well.

```js
var date = [  ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],  ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],  ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],  ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],  ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],  ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"]];

var values = [  [100, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 100, 100],  [87.5, 100, 100, 100, 87.5, 87.5],  [75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75],  [50, 50, 50, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5],  [62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 50, 37.5, 50],  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

var result = values
  // iterate over the values array
  .map(function(arr, i1) {
    // iterate over the inner array
    // in case you just want the first element as in your example then 
    // remove the first map method and replace `arr` with `values[0]` and `date[i1][i2]`  with `date[0][i2]` 
    return arr.map(function(n, i2) {
      // generate the required array object based on index
      return {
        y: n,
        // get the period from 2d array date using index
        periods: date[i1][i2] 
      }
    });
  });



document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null, 3);
```

```html
<pre id="data"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested mapping for the values.

```js
var values = [[100, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 100, 100], [87.5, 100, 100, 100, 87.5, 87.5], [75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75], [50, 50, 50, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5], [62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 50, 37.5, 50], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
    date = [["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"], ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"], ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"], ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"], ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"], ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"]],
    result = values.map(function (a, i) {
        return a.map(function (b, j) {
            return { d: date[i][j], y: b };
        });
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Except that's not what the example output is. (Because as you pointed out, the example output is unclear.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, some say so, others no.

Comment: (Geez, people, I woudn't *downvote* the answer because it's a bit speculative...)

Comment: @NinaScholz that's a nifty trick you did there with that css rule. Haven't seen that before :)

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten both of the arrays and then it's easy (assuming they are both of the same length):

```js
var date = [["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
    ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
    ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
    ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
    ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"],
    ["2015", "2004", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015"]];
    
    var values = [[100, 87.5, 87.5, 87.5, 100, 100],
    [87.5, 100, 100, 100, 87.5, 87.5],
    [75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75],
    [50, 50, 50, 62.5, 62.5, 62.5],
    [62.5, 62.5, 62.5, 50, 37.5, 50],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];
    
    var flatValues = [].concat.apply([], values);
    var flatDates = [].concat.apply([], date);
    
     var result = flatValues.map(function (n, i) {
                return ({ y: n, periods: flatDates[i] });
            });
            
    
    
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<pre id="data"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is this:

```
 //the concat will flatten the arrays.
 var result = [].concat.apply([],dates.map(function (subDates, i) {
      //Go throught the sub dates
      return subDates.map(function(date, j){
         //Create the object
         return { y: date, periods: values[i][j] };

     })
 }));

console.log(result);

//Output:
//[{"y":"2015","periods":100},{"y":"2004","periods":87.5},{"y":"2015","periods":87.5},{"y":"2015","periods":87.5},{"y":"2015","periods":100},...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to map it 2 times...

```
var resultData = date.map(function(item,indexDate){
  return item.map(function(year, indexYear){
     return {y:year,d:values[indexDate][indexYear]};
   }); 
});
```

you might also want to flatten the array look at this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/UoENNs7dkwCXNdLqSr8b?p=preview)